# display of raster in QGIS - cells are not rotated

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, python-2.7, mac

when viewing rotated rasters in QGIS - the overall raster is rotated (as designed), though each grid cell is not. (the nodata value doesn't appear to pick up as the default in QGIS either - -2.9999e+30 instead of -3e+30, but that might be a separate question).

[image: qgis screenshot].

and a closeup

[image: qgis closeup]

is this common for QGIS? viewing the same in 'the other GIS GUI' appears to rotate each cell.

i can add all the code - but the basic part is

```
def writeRast(gridbound, outTiff, grid, cellsize=1000, wkt=''):
    ''' lots of other stuff'''

    geotransform=(ulx, xres, xtheta, uly, ytheta, -yres)   
    drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    ds = drv.Create(outTiff, ncol, nrow, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32)  # Open the file
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    band.SetNoDataValue(-3e30)
    ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)  # Specify its coordinates
    if wkt != '':
        targproj = osr.SpatialReference()
        targproj.ImportFromWkt(wkt) 
    band.WriteArray(grid)
```

is there some setting in QGIS that would display each cell rotated? or something i'm missing in writing the raster with GDAL?

the geostransform params (for at least of the rasters) look something like:

```
(-247544.61184672063, 900.39636198453309, 1333.8944867046337, 694821.1191712627, 1333.8944867046337, -900.39636198453309)
```

tried with gdal 1.11.0 and 2.0.
on mac OSX, QGIS v 2.8.3.

Comment: Can you post the ds.GetGeoTransform tuple?

Comment: sure - edited question to include the tuple. admittedly, the input for the gt has tripped me up before - though i thought i finally made it since the raster displays in the correct location (and correct rotation) with other layers.

Comment: any thoughts?  issues with the geotransform?